# Unable to run .apk file in device or emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, calabash-android

I was trying to run a .apk file  through simulators to go through the application. But I can not able to connect it.
I tried with the following command

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platform-tools>adb install -r xxxbeta.apk
```

Here the result is showing success, But the application can’t open in emulators.

While I ran below command

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

when I am creating any android project and running then it is running in emulators. But no luck in connected devices.

But for .apk file it is not running.

Please suggest any idea if you have gone through this .

Comment: Just drag and drop the apk in emulator.It will install the apk automatically

Comment: hmm correct.. but still getting the adb path error.